# Simulation of newtonian planets

Tags: newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, simulations, planets, software

I am creating a simulation of planets with the help of newton's law([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Modern_form)) and everything works fine but I can't find any source how to calculate the perfect start velocity of a planet in order to orbit another planet in a perfect circular motion given following known parameters of both planets: mass, distance from mass center to mass center, G

following code to calculate acceleration:

```
calcBodyAcceleration(body1, body2) {

    var G = Settings.get("G");
    var mults = Settings.get("multipliers");

    var pos1 = Vec2.add(body1.position, body1.center);
    var pos2 = Vec2.add(body2.position, body2.center);

    var subtraction = Vec2.subtract(pos1, pos2);
    var dist2 = subtraction.magnitudeSq();
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dist2);

    var mass1 = body1.mass * mults.mass;
    var mass2 = body2.mass * mults.mass;

    var mass = mass1 * mass2;
    var force = G * (mass / dist2);

    subtraction.divide(dist).multiply(force).divide(mass1);

    body1.acceleration.subtract(subtraction);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distribution of orbital velocities in a disk galaxy for N-body simulation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308100/)

Comment: Though actually, it might be that [this question might be](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197661/25301) a more suitable duplicate.

Comment: I thought it would answer my question but it doesnt